# Chain multiple merge requests together in GitLab

Tags: git, gitlab, web-frontend

Is there a way to lock one merge request's status until another merge request passes?

e.g. if I am submitting API changes to an API project and frontend changes to a frontend project, I don't want the API changes to pass without the frontend changes or vice versa and I want to lock them together so the app won't break if my merge request gets approved. These are on different projects entirely but they rely on each other.

Comment: You could combine both these projects together, using sub-modules. With submodules you can manually resolve dependencies based on commits. [This info might help](https://twoguysarguing.wordpress.com/2010/11/14/tie-git-submodules-to-a-particular-commit-or-branch/)

Comment: How about leaving a message for the reviewer?

Comment: @LibinVarghese these are git submodules you are talking about, right? I'm looking for a GitLab-based solution preferably.

Comment: @JakubKania I do already, but since I work out of both projects daily and the reviewer sometimes changes I want to be more sure

Answer (score 5):

GitLab released [merge request dependencies](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/merge_requests/dependencies.html) in 12.2 (as a premium feature) which solve this exact issue. Merge request A can declare a dependency on merge request B which will block A from being merged until B is merged. This works across projects.

Comment: The only caveat I'll add to this is that the "View Changes" shows all the MRs that have not been merged. I could be missing something in this workflow.

It's doable, but still awkward; I'd like to see better support for this kind of workflow.

Answer (score 4):

We also have this problem from time to time. You can mark the frontends' merge request as work in progress by adding `WIP` in the beginning of the merge requests title. This will prevent the it from being merged. However, you have to remove the `WIP` manually when the API merge request is merged. Not an elegant solution, but the only one we came up with.

Edit: Well, the only one that does not involve yelling "Dude, do **not** merge that until Steve merged his!"